# YII Консольное приложение CConsoleCommand

Tags: cron, консоль, yii

Доброго времени!
Есть проект на Yii, нужно организовать выполнение операций по CRONу через консольные приложения.
Раз в месяц скрипт добавляет в таблицу запись.

```
class ZpEduCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
public function run($args) {
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO `text`(`ID`, `datee`, `ggg`) VALUES ("123123","2014-12-01 00:00:00","123")');
$command->execute();
}
}
```

Все хорошо работает.
Если дату ставлю так, то ничего не добавляется.

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO `text`(`ID`, `datee`, `ggg`) VALUES ("123123","' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '","123")');
$command->execute();
```

Comment: А MySQL ошибки какие выдает?

Comment: Не знаю как просмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри тут на форуме YII  - обсуждение вопроса.
http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12936

Comment: Всем спасибо! В конфиге консольного приложения, прописал часовой пояс: 
    
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',

Все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO `text`(`ID`, `datee`, `ggg`) VALUES (123123,?,123)');
$command->execute(array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

А ещё лучше

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO `text`(`ID`, `datee`, `ggg`) VALUES (123123, NOW(),123)');
$command->execute();
```

Comment: NOW() - это время сервера БД, он может не совпадать с временем клиента.

Comment: @Ale_x клиент через крон? Нет, конечно, в настройках может быть иное время указано, нежели в мускуле, но это маловероятно и практически гарантированно неверная архитектура.

Comment: Верхний вариант не работает. Нижний работает.
Все таки почему не работает с date() не понятно.
Если даже так сделаю, все равно не записывается:

    $monOpenModel = new Text;
    $monOpenModel->datee = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $monOpenModel->ID = "1";
    $monOpenModel->ggg = "1111";
    $monOpenModel->save();

Comment: @Etki А почему и нет? В php свои настройки времени (свой часовой пояс), может быть просто другой сервер, а в сервере БД другие настройки.

Comment: @Ale_x, потому что по крону не существует клиента.